# Web.config - Custom error pages not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have tried the following (and also tried with the commented-out uncommented instead) but only get an error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

In the web.config of a published website project:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"  existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <!--<error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="\Error\404.htm"/>-->
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="http://example.com/Error/404.htm"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

I try it by changing the url in the browser from `.../default.aspx` (which is fine) to `.../abc.aspx`.

Is this the correct way to redirect to error pages, or is there some mistake here?

**EDIT**

I've found that if I try `http://example.com/nonExistingPage` - it *does* redirect to the error page. But not from`http://example.com/Folder/nonExistingPage`

**EDIT 2**

The problem was partially solved by specifying the path after `example.com`. However - the site is published to `example.com/subfolder` and when someone navigates to `example.com/nonExistingFolder` - the custom error page is not shown.

Comment: ref edit 2: If the website is published to `example.com/subfolder` when it is not going to have any affect on someone trying to access `example.com/nonExistingFolder`. The web.config will only apply from the root of the website forward (i.e. `example.com/subfolder/nonExistingFolder`)

Comment: @kspearrin I actually have a web application published to the domain's root with a working web.config specifying a 404 page. But it fails here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this in `web.config` (includes 500 error support as well):

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        ...
        <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/500.htm">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404.htm" />
            <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/500.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        ...
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" prefixLanguageFilePath="" />
            <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/500.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" prefixLanguageFilePath="" />
        </httpErrors>
        ...
     </system.webServer>
     ...
</configuration>
```

I would also recommend using `.aspx` pages rather than `.htm` so that you can ensure the proper status code is set in the response headers.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<% Response.StatusCode = 404; %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    404 Error
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The relatively-relative path was the solution. I've tried relative paths before, but what was needed was the path _after_ the `example.com`.

Comment: This seems to be most of the answer, but I've updated the question - There's still a problem when navigating to a nonexistent page above the projects "root".

Comment: Unfortunately this solution actually submits a 200 response which is terrible.

Comment: @jenson-button-event Even with `Response.StatusCode = 404` ?

Comment: @jenson-button-event, try `Redirect` in `responseMode` if you see 200 instead of 404 in IIS logs

Comment: so its required to be aspx extention? what about for routes path that dont need extension on its path?