# custom errors in web.config do not work

Tags: asp.net, custom-error-handling

I have seen all of the related questions but none of it work.
I have even tried the httpErrors one but that just breaks my server. 
my code is:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Errors/Unauthorized.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Errors/Forbidden.aspx" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

I have tried Errors/Unau... , I have tried /Errors/Unau... but nothing works. Please what must I do for this thing to redirect correctly.

Comment: refer this, you will get more knowledge https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467835/web-config-custom-error-pages-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You can update Web.config as below

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/error">
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="/error/badrequest" />         
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error/notfound" />
  <error statusCode="414" redirect="/error/urltoolong" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/error/InternalServerError" />
  <error statusCode="503" redirect="/error/serviceunavailable" />
</customErrors>
```

This will work for all error code except 403: Forbidden

To handle 403 Forbidden error update web.config as below

```
  <system.webServer><httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="403" />     
    <error statusCode="403" path="/error/Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors></system.webServer>
```

The above code is working fine for me.
Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: The point wasn't to handle the 403. that was placed as an example. It doesn't handle any kind of error. I am trying to be redirected to the defaultRedirect and it isn't working. Also as I stated, httpErrors return a 500