# What is the correct syntax for specifying the ASP.NET MVC application root directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, http-error

I always use `~/` everywhere and it works fine. However I have an issue in the web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="~/Errors/404.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

It works fine when I speicfy the full path `path="http://localhost/MySite/Errors/404.html"`

How to reference http://localhost/MySite dynamically, so that I don't have to hard code localhost and can rename MySite in IIS to anything I like, not caring about the web.config.

The propsed solution in [Web.config - Custom error pages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467835/web-config-custom-error-pages-not-working) doesn't help unfortunatly, it produces the same problem.

**UPDATE:**
`<error statusCode="404" path="Errors/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>`
also works - if the 404 happens in that same directory.

`404.html` is definitely in an `Errors` folder the root directory of the application.
`<error statusCode="404" path="~/Errors/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>` doesn't work however.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web.config - Custom error pages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467835/web-config-custom-error-pages-not-working)

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's the same issue when use that solution

Comment: Because `system.webServer\httpErrors` is strictly an IIS setting and IIS won't try to interpret the ASP.NET `~` path, you can do nothing about this.

Comment: That's interesting as `~` is used throughout that web.config... How else can you get the application root directory in web.config for IIS settings then?

Comment: @Peete Each section of webconfig can be used by something else, that's why system.web/customErrors can have ~ while httpErrors don't. I suggest you check official documentation at [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/). To set it up correctly you can go with file mode with absolute file path, or you can get rid of `~` and use relative url in path, starting from root so: `/Errors/404.html` and setting mode to `responseMode="ExecuteURL"`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I read up on it and that's how it is. However I wonder if there is a way to enter a path relative to the root of the application, rather than the root of the server, without specifying the application name/folder

Comment: It may be difficult to realize that, as MSDN said:If you select Execute a URL on this site, the path must be a relative path. If you select Respond with a 302 redirect, the URL must be an absolute URL.